# Bug in the alignment of text?

Tags: text, alignment, textalignment

If I put text in a plot as an inset, the vertical alignment of the text is normally set to the mean line of text in general. It does not matter if one writes M or m the baseline will still be aligned, even though the real center of M and m is not the same. But a bug appears if the text contains a Subscript with both a high and low character. See the following example:

```
ListPlot[{}, Axes -> None, Frame -> None, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["m", Black, FontSize -> 25 pt], {-0.45, 0}, {0, 0}], 
Text[Style["M", Black, FontSize -> 25 pt], {-0.15, 0}, {0, 0}], 
Text[Style[Subscript["M", "M"], Black, FontSize -> 25 pt, SingleLetterItalics -> False], {0.15, 0}, {0, 0}], 
Text[Style[Subscript["M", "My"], Black, FontSize -> 25 pt, SingleLetterItalics -> False], {0.45, 0}, {0, 0}], 
Line[{{-1, -0.1}, {1, -0.1}}], Line[{{-1, 0.12}, {1, 0.12}}]}]
```

This produces the result shown below in which the last text is vertically elevated compared to the rest. Is there any possible fix for this issue?

[image]